# Updated to Firefox 16.0.2 - Trello not opening now

Tags: trello, firefox

Both myself and a colleague updated our main browser (Firefox 16) to the latest version (16.0.2) this morning and now we can't access our Trello board - nor the Development or Help ones.

Still works in Chrome or IE9 so we've got a backup way in.

Just thought I'd ask in here in case it's something that everyone else has noticed this morning?

Answer (score 3):

This is *probably* unrelated, but:

Fog Creek brought Trello down along with other services until the generators at the data center they're using can be refueled.

Looks like that's in progress and they might start bringing things back up, but don't quote me on that.

See here for updates: http://fogcreekstatus.typepad.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It was working for me up until about 8:30 am EST but nothing associated with Trello (other support sites) has worked since about 10:00 am EST.

Comment: Are you aware of the hurricane that has just hit New York?

Comment: Fog Creek are hosted in the Peer 1 colo facility. They have flooded diesel pumps and can't refuel the generators so have shut down.